# Car Rental Java lab

Tags: java, loops

Background:
When you rent a car from an agency, the key ring has several pieces of information: license plate, make and year of car, and usually a special code. This code could be used for some data processing within the
company's computers. This lab will practice determining that special car rental code from the license
plate.

Assignment:

1. The following sequence of steps will be used to convert a sample license plate into a car rental code.

a. A license plate consists of 3 letters followed by a space, followed by a 3-digit integer. For example, CPR 607.

b. Add up the ASCII values of the 3 letters, 67 + 80 + 82 = 229.

c. Add the sum of the letters to the 3-digit integer. For example, 229 + 607 = 836.

d. Take this sum (836) and determine the integer remainder after dividing by 26:
836 % 26 = 4.

e. Determine the 4th letter in the alphabet after the letter 'A': 4th letter after 'A' = 'E'

f. Combine the letter and the sum. Thus, we have CPR 607 = E836.

2. You may assume that all sample data will be in the format of 3 alphabet characters, then a space,
   followed by a 3-digit integer.

Thats my code 
import static java.lang.System.*;

```
public class CarRental 

   { private String licenseletters;
     private int licensenumber;


     public CarRental()
   {
     licenseletters="";
     licensenumber=0;

   }
     public CarRental(String a, int b) 
   {
     licenseletters=a;
     licensenumber=b;
   }

     public void setletters(String a, int b) 
   {
     licenseletters=a;
     licensenumber=b;
   }

     public int getASCIIone()
   {
     return (int)licenseletters.charAt(0); 
   }
     public int getASCIItwo()
   {
     return (int)licenseletters.charAt(1); 
   }
     public int getASCIIthree()
   {
     return (int)licenseletters.charAt(2); 
   }



    public int addASCII()
   {
    int total=  getASCIIone() + getASCIItwo() + getASCIIthree(); 
    return total;
   }
    public int adddigits()
   {
    int sum= addASCII() + licensenumber;
    return sum;
   }
    public int remainder()
   {
    int remain= adddigits()%26;
    return remain;

   }
    public int aftera()
   {
    int aftera= remainder()+65;
    return aftera;
   }
   public char letteraftera()
   {
    char letteraftera= (char)aftera();
    return letteraftera;
    }
     public String tostring()
    {
     return ""+ letteraftera() + adddigits();
     }

     }
```

Thats my runner code and I am getting an error at the constructor part right before the word new

```
 import static java.lang.System.*;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CarRentalRunner
 {
  public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  for(int b=0; b<10; b=b+1){
  Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Make=");
  String carmake= keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Model=");
  String carmodel=keyboard.nextLine();


  System.out.print("Enter the license plates number");
  String a= keyboard.next();

  int c= keyboard.nextInt();
  CarRentalRunner Java = new CarRentalRunner(a,b);
  System.out.println(Java);
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: `CarRentalRunner` has no construtor (with the supplied parameters), I think you meant `CarRental`

Comment: It says cannot find symbol

Comment: Side note: `Java` is a terrible, meaningless variable name.

Answer (score 1):

`CarRentalRunner` has no construtor (with the supplied parameters), I think you meant `CarRental`

```
CarRentalRunner Java = new CarRentalRunner(a,b);
```

Should probably be

```
CarRental rental = new CarRental(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the error message you're getting it'll say something along the lines of there's no constructor defined that matches `new CarRentalRunner(a, b);`

And so if you look in the CarRentalRunner.java file you can see that it is indeed true that there is no constructor that matches.

You most likely want to be instantiating your CarRental class instead of the runner.